# Cocoa Touch begin command AFTER viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have an application in which I am required to connect to the internet after a view is loaded. However, if I put this code in the viewDidLoad method the parent view freezes, and then unfreezes after the connection onto the new view. However, I would like the new view to load FIRST, and then to start the connection. I tried using viewDidAppear:, however I am getting the same issue.

Also, will any animations continue playing during the connection? Will the UI be responsive? If not, is multithreading the way to go?

Here is some of my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Do some other view initialization
    //Connect is a class I use to connect to the internet
    [Connect getData:someString];
}
```

When I put the code in viewDidAppear the same thing happens.

Connection code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Also, I forgot to mention that I am running a regular expression as well after the connection.

Answer (score 1):

As the name of the method says, the view has already been loaded when `viewDidLoad` executes.

Generally, be sure to use [asynchronous connections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) to connect to the internet. Never block the main thread.

Comment: Then why is the view not being shown until AFTER the connection?

OK

Comment: Probably because you are using a synchronous connection that blocks the main thread. But how are we supposed to tell if you don't show us your code? (Also, _loading_ a view does not mean that it is also being displayed. But that is probably not the problem in your case.)

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation that explains how to use asynchronous connections. This is almost always how you should manage connections, rather than spawning your own threads.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier than you may think.

All you need is some thread management. On the view did Do:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(yourMethod:) toTarget:yourTarget withObject:yourObject];
```

and later in another part do:

```
- (void)yourMethod:(id)sender{
//download the info but do not update the GUI

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updatingTheGUI:) withObject:yourObject waitUntilDone:NO]


}

- (void)updatingTheGUI:(id)sender{
//Update your GUI

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will notice that the `viewDidLoad` method [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) of `UIViewController` states:

> ...Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.

This doesn't necessarily mean that it's called after the view is displayed on screen.

To answer your other questions, if you make your network request the way you have described, no, animations will not continue playing while the request is in progress and no, you can't guarantee that the UI will be responsive. This is because the network request will take an unknown amount of time. Therefore, if you make the request on the main thread, the main thread will be blocked for that period of time, however long it takes.

And, as for the last question, *is multithreading the way to go?* As others have stated, the easiest and probably most popular way of handling this is to initialize the `NSURLConnection` with `initWithRequest:delegate:`. The delegate being your `UIViewController` or `Connect` class, or whatever class you want to conform to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol and use the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods to process the downloaded data. `NSURLConnection` will do the work asynchronously and keep the main thread free to handle animations, displaying the UI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds a bad idea for your app. performance but try giving a delay or sleep in between to check if it works that way. Later try to implement the asynchronous call as someone earlier stated..